# Translate stripe Curl request to Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios

Hello I'd like to translate this to axios!

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/search \
  -u sk_test_ReallyLongkey: \
  --data-urlencode query="status:'active' AND metadata['order_id']:'6735'" \
  -G
```

I attempted something like this but it doesn't seem to work

```
const request = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/search',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.STRIPE_SECERET,
      pass: '',
    },
    data: qs.stringify({
      status: 'active',
    }),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    },
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to make a get request using Axios and use URL query parameters.

```
axios.get("https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/search",{
params:{status:"active"},
headers:{"authorization":`bearer ${myApiKey}`}
});
```

Comment: His concern is post request.

Comment: No, you are wrong his concern is to translate the above curl request. It is clearly a get request that is needed to be made to the server which is indicated by the "-G" flag and also mentioned on the stripe API docs https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/search?lang=curl